# Laravel queue works only if started manually, not with Kernel command

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have the following `Kernel.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        \Log::info("hit");
        $schedule->command('queue:restart')->everyFiveMinutes();
        $schedule->command('queue:work')->name('queue_work_name')->withoutOverlapping()->runInBackground();

    }
}
```

and a cron job set to run every minute... it prints correctly the `"hit"` in the logs, but no sign of the queue to be running... however, if i go to the terminal and run `php artisan queue:work --once`, it just works fine

What am i missing

Comment: You probably don't want to use the scheduler to run the queue workers as they are ultimately different things. You should look into supervisord https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: This is not queue, but Task Scheduling. They are two different things.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Comment: @AdemirŠehić It's not always possible...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this code to crontab?

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Above code checks for the scheduled commands and executes them.

To open crontab in linux use `crontab -e`.

Comment: `schedule:run` is called regularly as supposed to